# Why everytime I run Sail Up it is creating a new container in docker?

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I am new to Docker and Laravel. Why every time I run `bash ./vendor/bin/sail up` in my terminal it keeps creating a new container in docker. I'm not sure if this is normal in docker or I have issues on my docker-composer file?

[image]

I have added a phpmyadmin service to access my database in my localhost. Please see my docker-composer.yml file.

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        environment:
            - PMA_HOST=mysql
            - PMO_PORT=3306
        networks:
            - sail
        ports:
            - 8001:80
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Comment: try this :sail down && sail up --build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's normal and your compose file is correct, This happened when you run `sail up` these containers not run in background and when you press `Ctrl+C` these containers will terminate then when you run again docker create new containers as you see.

If you want to run these container in background do this:

```
sail up -d
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for confirming.